# What’s the meaning of the abbreviation (ז"פ)?

Tags: hebrew, translation, acronyms

What’s the meaning the abbreviation (ז"פ)?

Example as found in [Sefer HaGoralot](https://seforimcenter.com/Sefer-HaGoralot---Rabbi-Chaim-Vital__p-5559.aspx) by Rabbi Chaim Vital:
“ וזאת היא התפלה שצריך להתפלל קודם שישליך הגורל: אנא בכח גדולת ימינך תתיר צרורה ז"פ.”

Thanks,
Jardel

Comment: Where is this quote from?

Comment: It is probably "זה פירושו" - "This is the explanation" or similarly "זה פשוט" - "This is simple i.e. the basic understanding"

Comment: Hi, Dov! This quotes is in the ספר הגורלות.

Comment: Could it mean 7 times, meaning that you have to say the prayer אנא בכח seven times before casting the lots?

Comment: @AvrahamYitzchok is correct. ז״פ means to say it means seven times. That you repeat the Ana b’Koach, meaning the 42 letter name associated with the Matriarchs, seven times. That 42 is the Mispar Katan of the names of the Matriarchs and seven times emphasizes the connection of the 3 Patriarchs with the 4 Matriarchs for a total of seven times.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I think it might be seven times. Because in the next line he says it must be done for the sake of the 7 Tzadikim (Abraham, Yitzchak, Jacob, Moshe, Aaron, Phineas and David).
In the next line he also says that the verse “Shavatenu cabel…”, in “Ana bechoach”, should be pronounced only once (“פעם אחד”).

Answer (score 5):

My best guess is ז'פעמים, or 7 times, similar to what we see many time ג"פ for "three times".